# DIR-615 lose internet connection after 3 minutes

Tags: router, nat

I got a new DLink DIR-615 routeur. DSL model connects fine. Connected PCs connects to the internet fine (wireless, wired) fine too. After ~3 minutes, connected PCs cannot go to the internet. Web pages goes timeout, sometimes google talk stays on (working). From the router admin page, pings works correctly (on google.ca), so the connection is active.

pc --> routeur --> internet: fail

pc --> router: ok

router --> internet: ok

could it be firewall related? I've read there's a [SPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateful_Packet_Inspection) firewall enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Update the firmware, but don't use the router update functionality, otherwise will look for the nearest server that probably don't have the update you need.

I usually use the UK ftp site ftp://ftp.dlink.co.uk/

Comment: I have HW rev E1. Router sais it has the latest vestion. Seems the link you gave me doesn't have firmware beyong D1 (2008)

Comment: ftp://ftp.dlink.co.uk/dir_products/dir-615/

Answer (score 0):

How many devices do you have connected?  Try just one wired device (unplug all others, disconnect wireless devices) see if it works or if same issue.  If same, reset router(backup any custom config) to factory defaults see if problem still happens.  Beyond that there are other troubleshooting can try but sounds like might need replacement.  May want to remove router directly connecting to a computer, most ISPs will make you do this when troubleshooting anyways.

Comment: my last router was working kinda fine (netgear). I'll replace the new dlink. I disabled SPI and everything that could block connections, and it still does it.